# How can I put each folder name in a full path in one cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
C:\Users\TimCOOK\Downloads\mysql-shell-8.0.31-windows-x86-64bit\lib\mysqlsh\plugins\plugins_plugin
```

What I'm trying to do it is to put each folder name in one cell in Excel when I paste the full path. I have tried using Macro and Flash Fill and neither worked. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Expectation:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C: | Users | TimCOOK | Downloads | mysql-shell-8.0.31-windows-x86-64bit | ... |

(each name in one cell in a row)

Comment: with Office 365 use TEXTSPLIT or in vba you can use Split and return the resulting array to the cells.

Comment: Which cells (column) contain the path, and which is the first column of the result (I'm guessing in the same row)? Or are you replacing the path entry cell?

Comment: VBA `SPLIT()`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Text to Columns wizard in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) to separate the different parts of the file path into separate columns:

1. Select the column that contains the full file paths.
2. Go to the *Data* tab in the ribbon and click on the *Text to Columns* button.
3. In the *Text to Columns* wizard, select the *Delimited* option and click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
4. In the next step, select the *Other* option and enter the backslash `\` in the box. This tells Excel to use the backslash as the delimiter.
5. Click <kbd>Finish</kbd> to complete the process.

In VBA you can use use the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns) and set the delimiter to `\` or `Application.PathSeparator`.

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="\", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

This will turn

[image]

into

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've tried different methods, and Text to Columns seemed to have worked the best.